# How to specify which object in an ICollection you want to pull out

Tags: c#

I have an ICollection of CurJob objects.  I need to access properties from a specific one of those objects.  The way that I am doing it now just gives me access to the first object in the collection.  I know that I am telling it to use .First() and I'm realizing that may not be what I want.  So basically there could only be 1 in this collection or there could be an infinite number.  I want to be able to grab the specific one I need based on a property called entryNumber.  I need the highest entryNumber to be the object that I am exposing.  Not sure how to handle thought.  Any thoughts?

```
// Find the job we just submitted
CurJob runningJob = CurJob.Find("Some Job", StateType.Any, server).ToList().First();
```

Comment: You are looking for a specific `entryNumber` but you also want the highest?  This sounds contradictory.

Comment: If there could be an *infinite number of items* then there is not necessarily one that has the highest number. Do you mean **there could be an infinite number of items** or **the number of items is finite but unbounded**? Those are very, **very** different things. You can sort a finite unbounded list; you can't sort an infinite list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. Just order by entryNumber before picking the first one.

```
CurJob job = CurJob.Find("Some Job", StateType.Any, server).ToList()
                   .OrderByDescending(j => j.entryNumber).First();
```

**Edit**

You'll need to use the System.Linq namespace for this.

**Edit**

If you're looking for all the jobs that match a specific entryNumber, not the highest, try something like this:

```
var jobs = CurJob.Find("Some Job", StateType.Any, server).ToList()
                   .Where(j => j.entryNumber == X);
```

(Replace X with the number you're looking for)

Comment: The only problem (my mistake failed to mention) is that I won't know the entry number.  So I just need to take the highest one.

Comment: @Tim The first block of code in this answer will do that.

Comment: Ah, you're right because it's grabbing the first one from the descending list which would put the highest entry number first.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Are you sure that it's better this way then using `Max()` and `Select()`?